# Diagonal div border css with background image

Tags: css, html, diagonal

I'm trying to get 2 div's next to eachother with a diagonal space between them.
I've seen multiple tutorials en stackoverflow's about diagonal divs, but they all do this by using 2 borders for the div with a solid color and use the diagonal line those create. But I want to have pictures/background image instead of a solid color. And maybe even other content like text that go's under the diagonal line. And that's not possible when using borders, as a border is outside the div. (floatright with overflow hidden or something for the content.)

Could anybody here give me a hint how to achieve this?
My tests all ended with nothing close to wat I want.
Something like this:

[image]

Thanks a lot if anybody could point this out for me.

Comment: You should probably post code that you've tried so far and/or create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) demonstrating that code, otherwise this is likely to get closed.

Comment: Hmm, tricky. I guess maybe you could do something with CSS transforms, but the 2D transforms won't do trapezoidal shapes like you want here.

Comment: I will make a jsFiddle and post it here, somewhere 2morow or later this week. It's christmas time now ;)

Answer (score -1):

> add following style to the second image

```css
<style>
    .img2{
    margin-right:-10px;
    }
    <style>
```